# How to make inline description* list left-aligned and hyphenated?

Tags: lists, enumitem, hyphenation, description, inline

I am having a simple doc:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inlinedesc}{description*}{1}
\setlist[inlinedesc]{itemjoin={{ $\odot$ }}, itemjoin*={{ and }}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7.2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{fussy}

Here comes \verb+inlinedesc+:

\begin{inlinedesc}
\item[first] about the first item
\item[second] THIS CANNOT BE EMPTY
\item[third] about the third item
\item[first] about the first item
\item[second] THIS CANNOT BE EMPTY
\item[third] about the third item
\end{inlinedesc}

more text ... more text ...

\end{fussy}
\end{document}
```

How do I get rid of horizontal spaces marked with red?

[image]

I would rather have the contents left-aligned, ideally also hyphenated (but not the list item head/term: just the list item body).

Thanks!

Comment: I would have thought using `\raggedright` would do the trick. Since it did not I suspect the problem is in the spaces between items.

Comment: using `mode=unboxed` as an option passed to the `inlinedesc` produces something better, but has overfull hbox

Comment: Add `afterlabel={\unskip\space}` or possibly `afterlabel={\unskip\hspace{\labelsep}}`.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. [I reported it.](https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/issues/38)

Comment: It’s a bug, indeed. I’ve posted a workaround in GitHub.